# CheckboxPreference state is not changed when calling onContentChanged

Tags: android, preferenceactivity

I have a `Restore default settings`option in my [PreferenceActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html). After the settings are changed I call [onContentChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html#onContentChanged%28%29). But for some reason the visual state of my [CheckboxPreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/CheckBoxPreference.html) is not updated.

The only workaround if found is to update the state manually:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
boolean autoStartValue = prefs.getBoolean("auto_start", true);

CheckBoxPreference autoStartPref = (CheckBoxPreference)findPreference("auto_start");
autoStartPref.setChecked(autoStartValue);

// Notify that the preferences changed
EditPreferencesActivity.this.onContentChanged();
```

What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to register the `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener()`
and update your preference yourself.

```js
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // Set up a listener whenever a key changes
    getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    // Unregister the listener whenever a key changes
    getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}

public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {
    Log.i(TAG, "o--> onSharedPreferenceChanged");
    Preference p = findPreference(key);
    if(p instanceof CheckBoxPreference){
        CheckBoxPreference checkBoxPref = (CheckBoxPreference) p;
        checkBoxPref.setChecked(prefs.getBoolean(key, true));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To change a shared preference value without using the UI (i.e. the PreferenceScreen) use an android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor:

```
final Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putBoolean("auto_start", true);
editor.commit();
```

The changed value will be reflected when you open the preference screen without further notification.

Comment: But to my understanding this will not update the CheckboxPreferences checked state if the PreferenceActivity is already visible.